# Refreshing JWT automatically before expiration

Tags: android, jwt

I am new to android, I am currently trying to implement basic JWT authentication in my app.  I use Laravel 5 on the server with JWT.  Sessions are set to expire every 60 minutes on my server.

What I want to do now is write a function that runs globally in the app, doesn't matter which activity you are on the function should execute every 55 minutes and refresh my JWT on the server.

I would also like to know the cons with such an implementation, if the app is closed what happens? Will the timer still run in the background?

I saw a couple of JWT libraries available for Android but I use Volley for my HTTP requests and didn't know how I could combine those two libraries to achieve my desired result.

Comment: Rather than running every 55th minute, it would be better if the token is refreshed after it has expired. You will get 401 ERROR as response in any API call, if the token has expired.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to refresh the tokens at the time when you get the unauthorized error. Here is the sample example:

```
@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    try {
        if(error.getResponse().getStatus() == 401){
            //your service for refreshing the token
         } else{
                JsonElement json = (JsonElement) error.getBodyAs(JsonElement.class);
                String err = json.getAsJsonObject().get("err").getAsString();
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle the exception

    }
}
```

The benefit of this structure is that there are no redundant background calls for refreshing the token automatically. It will only update the token when it is required.